# Accommodating heterogenous receivers in a Go constraint

Tags: go, generics, constraints

### Context

This question is about defining the canonical, proper, or best-practice approach for defining **type-constraints for types with a mix between pointer and non-pointer receivers**. I define a few terms for clarity purposes:

- Constraint: Interface types when provided as a type-argument. Restricts the type parameter to satisfy all elements of the interface.
- Type set: The intersection of the type-sets of all elements within the interface; with non-interface types having a type-self containing themselves.
- Approximation element: Represented as `~` in Go, this operator effectively means  "any type whose underlying type is X", provided that "X"'s own underlying type is itself.

---

### Problem

I elucidate the problem by example. Consider the following:

```
// Type A and pointer receiver
type A struct {
  s string
}
func (a *A) String() string {
  return a.s
}

// Type constraint C
type C interface {
  A
  String() string
}

func show [T C] (x T) {
    fmt.Println(x.String())
}

func main() {
  a := A{s:"a"}
  show(a)
}
```

Attempting to run this code shall fail with the following error:

> A does not satisfy C (method String has no pointer receiver)

Evidently, pointer-receivers are defined on *pointers* to type A, not A itself. This can be resolved by simply changing the constraint `C` to be defined on type `*A`, and call show with the appropriate reference:

```
// Type constraint C
type C interface {
  *A
  String() string
}

// Adjustment to main
func main() {
  // ...
  show(&a)
}
```

So far all is well, but how does one resolve the situation where type `A` has *both* pointer and non-pointer type receivers?

```
// Type A, normal receiver, and pointer receiver
type A struct {
  s string
}
func (a A) Show() {
  fmt.Println(a.s)
}
func (a *A) String() string {
  return a.s
}

// Type constraint C: ??? 
type C interface {
  A
  Show()
  String() string
}

func show1 [T C] (x T) {
    fmt.Println(x.String())
}

func main() {
  a := A{s:"a"}
  show(a)
}
```

Constraint `C` requires that all instances of type `C` implement `Show` *and* `String`. But `Show` is defined on `A`, and `String` on `*A`. Reconciling these now becomes more difficult

---

### Attempted solutions

I attempt to address the problem with a variety of solutions, which I sectioned below:

1. By type approximation
2. By union type
3. By type parameter

#### Approximation element

The first approach might be to use an *approximation element*. However, this is used to describe the set of all types whose *underlying* type is `T`, and it appears that pointers to `T` aren't counted as a derived type:

```
// Type constraint C
type C interface {
  ~struct{s string} // You may not use A here, for it's underlying type is not itself :) 
  String() string
  Show()
}
```

#### Type Union

Another approach is to try and use a type union. However, this can already be seen as flawed, given Go generics requires that every member of a type set implement it. Therefore, it cannot be that `String` shall automagically be resolved to use `*A`, and `Show` to `A`

```
// Type constraint C
type C interface {
  A | *A   // A does not satisfy C (method String has pointer receiver) 
  String() string
  Show()
}
```

#### Type parameter adjustment

The last approach is to do away with a single monolithic constraint. After all, it can't satisfy both the normal and pointer-receive methods. However, attempting to inline two distinct constraints runs into problems itself.

```
func show [P interface{ String() string}, T interface{Show()}] (x T) {
    x.Show()
    p := P(&x) // Cannot convert &x (value of type T) to type P
    fmt.Println(p.String())
}
```

It seems that I am not able to correctly define `P` such that I can convince the compiler it is a pointer of `T`. Despite `*T` implementing the constraint imposed on `P`.

So my question becomes: How does one approach defining constraints for types with multiple receivers in Go? Must distinct constraints be defined, or is it possible to perform it all in one? Is there some syntactic trick I am missing that bridges types to their pointers?

---

### Update

Based on some feedback, I'm updating my question with an real-world use case to try and make the MVE more understandable:

- Suppose I want to write an interface for a database. This database has a number of tables.
- Each table has a certain number of columns with different fields.
- In Go, we can represent each field with a `struct`. Now, in order to make our interface flexible, we can write a generic interface which returns row-type `T` when invoked.
- However, we also want row type `T` to provide our interface with a query string. Therefore, we define a `Query() string` method on `*T`.

The reason we want to do that on the pointer-receiver is because it is the recommended practice for structs:

> If the receiver is a large struct or array, a pointer receiver is more efficient. How large is large? Assume it’s equivalent to passing all its elements as arguments to the method. If that feels too large, it’s also too large for the receiver.

[Go Wiki - Receiver Type](https://go.dev/wiki/CodeReviewComments)

Note that when using non-generic code, you can invoke value and pointer receiver methods on the type irrespective of whether it is a pointer or not. Since this doesn't work with Generics out of the box, it is a part of why I wrote my question.

Comment: Your question isn't quite right . . . the problem that you're facing isn't that the method's receiver types are heterogeneous (because after all, all of them will happily accept a pointer receiver), it's that you want to express the relation "`*T` implements `Interface`" as a constraint on `T`. That said, I don't fully understand why you would want this. Why not simply write `show(&x)`? If you're happy for `String()` to operate on a copy of `x`, then why does it require a pointer to begin with?

Comment: @ruakh Here is an example to help. Let's say you define an interface for a type that will be used with a database. The type represents a table row entry. To ensure your interface is generic, you define it as returning the type T (which shall be defined as a struct representing that table row fields), but that type itself should be able to return a query string as well (which should be defined on pointer-receiver *T, since it would be costly to copy the large struct into a non-pointer receiver method). Now you have an analogy for why you want `String()` to operate on the receiver.

Comment: @ruakh I also added this example to the question to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the example is too simplistic vs. your real problem, but why exactly do generics feel like the right way to solve this?

Plain interfaces are the best way to address what's in the question:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    s string
}

func (a A) String() string {
    return a.s
}

func (a *A) Show() {
}

type StringShower interface {
    fmt.Stringer
    Show()
}

func show(x StringShower) {
    fmt.Println(x.String())
    x.Show()
}

func main() {
    a := A{s: "a"}
    show(&a)
}
```

If it's because you need to return or do something with the value as the caller provided, you can use that interface as a generic. It works fine with heterogenous receivers:

```golang
func show[T StringShower](x T) T {
    fmt.Println(x.String())
    return x
}

a = &A{s: "a"}
a = show(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The example is just a minimal example to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish with generics. It is indeed possible to use an interface to capture both the normal and pointer based receivers in it. The "right" method is then automatically called when you invoke either method in the interface. But this is not the case for generic functions, which is what I'm trying to figure out. So the goal of the question is moreso: What is the right/best approach for generics that take types with different types of function receivers.

Comment: Hmm. Can you add a realistic scenario to the question instead of one without context? It's going to be hard to give a helpful answer if the examples are better solved in other ways. I understand what you're trying to do, just not why you're trying to do it.

Comment: Yes, consider the following: I have a database with a table. The table has a number of fields (columns). I represent these fields in a struct in Go. I wish to write generic code for any table, therefore I make my database interface generic on input type `T`. The interface must return `T` for a query. It must also ask `T` for a query string. To avoid copying structs, a pointer-receiver should be used (`*T`). Now you see where the complication comes in. While Go normally allows both value-receivers and pointer-receivers to be called, it cannot auto-discriminate in Generics.

Comment: Updated my example. Should be phrased better there and I don't run out of characters :D

Answer (score 0):

In my experimenting since posting, I have found that the following is *one possible solution*. What I am basically doing here is defining two constraints, one for the normal type, one for the pointer type:

- **Normal type interface**: `T interface { Show() }`: Defines a method `Show` which operates directly on `T`
- **Pointer type interface**: `P interface { *T; String () string }`: Defines a method `String` which operates on `*T`, the pointer to `T`.

Putting this together and I get:

```
func show [P interface {*T; String() string}, T interface{Show()}] (x T) {
    x.Show()
    p := P(&x)
    fmt.Println(p.String())
}
```

However, to use the pointer receiver you still have to do a cast. I find the casting to not be very elegant. See the full source code for this solution [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Micrified/455e7e4dc1aa6bb1a28898add4e38430). I am interested in finding better ways to do this, so will await other proposals/explanations.